# How would you merge 30 point clouds?

Tags: python, 3d, point-clouds, open3d

I have 30 point clouds that were taken in a time sequence, and I need to merge them in a single point cloud, hopefully obtaining a more complete point cloud.

I'm using python with open3D.

Right now I created a function that first performs global registration between tWo point clouds, and then I run colored ICP (my point clouds have color information too).

I tried merging the first point cloud with the second, then this result with the third, and so on.
Alternatively, I also merged the first with the second, the third and the fourth,..., and then merged again the pairs until I obtained one final point cloud.

The results are pretty similar. Is there any other way?

Comment: How many different ways do you need?  Why do you need more than 1?

Comment: There are as many ways to order the merge operations as there are ways to organise a direct-elimination tournament with n-1 games between n players.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a faster method, you might want to consider using the voxel_down_sample function in Open3D. This function reduces the number of points in your point cloud by creating a voxel grid and taking the centroid of each voxel. This can significantly reduce the size of your point cloud and make the merging process faster.

import open3d as o3d

pcd1 = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("cloud1.pcd")
pcd2 = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("cloud2.pcd")

pcd1_down = pcd1.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)
pcd2_down = pcd2.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)

merged_pcd = pcd1_down + pcd2_down

o3d.io.write_point_cloud("merged_cloud.pcd", merged_pcd)

Comment: I'm doing this too! Actually I have one question about downsizing with voxels. Wont that reduce the "quality" of the point clouds, especially the final one because it is a result of deverão downsizings?